# How to re-add removed drive to raid 1 mdadm array on another machine?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

I recently was having trouble with a server randomly shutting down. I figured it was signs of disk failure, so I went about removing and swapping a drive from the raid 1 mdadm array.

There were two drives in the array like this:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0   7.5G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   7.5G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sda2    8:2    0 924.1G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0   924G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0   7.5G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   7.5G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sdb2    8:18   0 924.1G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0   924G  0 raid1 /
```

I did not know which drive would be faulty so I chose sdb. I removed sdb from both md0 and md1, and rebuilt the array on a new hard drive overnight.

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1 --remove /dev/sdb1
mdadm /dev/md1 --fail /dev/sdb2 --remove /dev/sdb2
```

[replace]

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2
```

In the morning it turns out that the faulty drive was sda, and the server can no longer boot.

EDIT: I should point out that the rebuilt failed overnight and the new disk was not fully rebuilt.

How can I set up the drive I took out so that it thinks it is still part of the mdadm array? I have another linux computer on hand.